# SLIME not finding Clozure or Hyperspec docs

Tags: common-lisp, slime, ccl

I just fresh-installed Emacs + SLIME + CCL on Ubuntu following the steps described in clozure.com and everything seems to work fine. However *apropos* prints this output when asked for a particular keyword:

```
MAKE-ARRAY
  Function: (not documented)
CCL::COMP-MAKE-ARRAY-1
  Function: (not documented)
CCL::MAKE-ARRAY-1
  Function: (not documented)
CCL::MAKE-ARRAY-CTYPE
  Function: (not documented)
```

And when asking for the hyperspec of a selected region, a small console pops up with the message "can't execvp lynx: no such file or directory".

How to solve either of these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can't execvp lynx: no such file or directory

install lynx or change default browser in prefered applications.
As variant:

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic)
(setq browse-url-generic-program "your browser, i.e. google-chrome")
```

> However apropos prints this output when asked for a particular keyword

may be symbols just haven't documentation string(I'm sbcl user and not now about ccl)?

> asking for the hyperspec

```
(setq common-lisp-hyperspec-root "path to HyperSpec directory")
```

Comment: I didn't even know what Lynx was! Installed, hence issue solved. As for *apropos*, chances are indeed that docs are not included - as they just implement a standard-defined part of the lang.

Comment: Find definition of interested for you functions in ccl's source codes and if they not contain documentation string that means there is no chance :)